# Add a button at the end of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add a button at the bottom of a table view to handle a `loadMore()` function.

What I tried to do is to programmatically define a button inside a custom cell and try to append it when the numberOfRows is superior than the tableView items count. It results in a fatal error "Index out of range".

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return itemArray.count + 1
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let loadCell = itemList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadMore", for: indexPath) as! LoadMore
        
   let cell = itemList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "normalCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemBox
            
   if indexPath.row > itemArray.count {
     return loadCell
   }
   return cell
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error as I specified one more row in the numberOfRowsInSection func.

Comment: The code you've shown shouldn't produce that bug. `items.count` that's `itemList.count`? Also, rows starts at 0, so if you have one item, let's say 1 + 1 button, indices Path.row will be 0 and 1, so you'll put the load cell, never since it will never be > to 1? if `indexPath.row >= itemsList.count`. But its unclear because `itemList` seems to be a UITableView, not an array. And you should test before which cell to dequeue.

Comment: `indexPath.row` will never be greater than `itemList.count` as the first index is 0.  The test you want is `if indexPath.row == itemList.count`

Comment: To Larme : I corrected my post so it's correct. 
To Paulw11 : I tried your solution but still getting the fatal error "Index out of range"

Comment: OK my bad, I was declaring variables outside of itemArray range so it's working now. I guess this is the way I implement my button that is not working now. Thank you guys.

Comment: Unrelated but put the `let loadCell = ...` line into the `if` clause and add an `else` clause. It's quite inefficient to dequeue always both cells.